# Google Analytics Link Account Not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I have been trying to track more then 3 sites of mine by using a single google analytics code. In this case I have tried to track it using following code which I got from a blog.

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  //Load the plugin.
  ga('require', 'linker');

  // Define which domains to autoLink.
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.abc.com', 'www.def.com']);
  ga('create', 'UA-XXX8XXX4-1', 'auto', {
      'allowLinker': true,
      'cookieDomain': 'none'
    });

  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

where www.abc.com is the site for which I have created a property in my google analytic's account by the name of "ABCPropery" and the tracking ID against this account which I got is UA-XXX8XXX4-1.

Now my problem is it always track the page views on www.abc.com but not on www.def.com.

So, what I want is to track the page views of abc.com and def.com. While I have added the above script in master pages of both the sites (i.e. www.abc.com, www.def.com).

Can any one help me on this that how can I track both the site using a single code? And what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem but you are setting the cookie domain twice, once with the "auto" parameter and once in your configuration object. Plus the only valid usage for cookieDomain "none" seems to be using GA on localhost. I suggest you start by removing the cookieDomain setting from the config object.

Comment: Do I need to create separate properties in my GoogleAnalytics account for www.def.com as well ??

Comment: No (that's the point of cross domain tracking that everything goes into the same property and multiple domains are counted as one).

Comment: can you provide a link to the blog where you got the code you are using? Having that context might help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use following:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

//Load the plugin.
ga('require', 'linker');

// Define which domains to autoLink.
ga('linker:autoLink', ['www.abc.com', 'www.def.com']);
ga('create', 'UA-XXX8XXX4-1', 'auto', {
    'allowLinker': true
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
```